# Determine real executable when invoking dynamic linker directly

Tags: c, linux, ld

I am running an executable through my dynamic linker directly, calling `execve()` with the path to the dynamic linker. However, unlike when executing a binary directly, `/proc/self/exe` is a symlink to the dynamic linker rather than a symlink to the binary, which breaks certain applications that depend on the standard behaviour (mainly OpenJDK). Is there any way to determine the real executable path of a binary executed through a dynamic linker? Is there another file in `/proc` that I can read to get the path, then have a hacky `LD_PRELOAD` override for `readlink()` that translates accesses to `/proc/*/exe` to the real path?

For a bit of background - I'm trying to get fakechroot with the custom ELF loader parameter working for OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably too easy and you've already thought about it, but can't you simply read `/proc/*/cmdline` and find the real executable as an argument to `ld`? Only if you have detected that `/proc/*/exe` is a symlink to `ld`, of course.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that :) but seeing as it's been over a week with no other responses, I suppose this is the only way.